# Could you explain part of this function that begins with " if not exist...."?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION event_partition()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   _tbl text := to_char(NEW.the_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
BEGIN
   ***IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
      JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'  -- your schema
      AND    c.relname = _tbl
      AND    c.relkind = 'r') THEN***

      EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I (CHECK (the_date >= %L AND
                                              the_date <  %L)) INHERITS (events)'
              , _tbl
              , to_char(NEW.the_date,     'YYYY-MM-DD')
              , to_char(NEW.the_date + 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
              );
   END IF;

   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(_tbl) || ' VALUES ($1.*)'
   USING NEW; 

   RETURN NULL;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION event_partition() SET search_path=public;
```

Comment: If the query that follows `NOT EXIST` returns 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

It's querying the database's internal table list ([`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-class.html)) to see if the table `_tbl` already exists in the `public` schema, and creating it if it doesn't.

You should be able to remove the check, and just use a [`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html) statement instead.